# UILabel Dynamic height problem

Tags: ios, ios4, uilabel

I have one `UILabel` and one button under the label. Height of the label is dynamic. I use this: `[label sizeToFit];` But when the size of the label raise, it wrap the button. How can I rearrange the view ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
[label sizeToFit];
btn.frame = label.frame;
```

Thereby setting your button to the same size as the label... or manually adding some padding like this:

```
[label sizeToFit];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(label.frame.origin.x - 10, label.frame.origin.y - 10, label.frame.size.width + 20, label.frame.size.height + 20);
```